# Method of including an external version controlled project within another

Tags: svn, version-control

I wish to include the dll output by a project built from an external SVN repository within my own project. What is the best approach to achieve this aim.

As the external project svn:ignores the bin\release folder I don't think I can use an svn:external.

Building the latest version and copying across the dlls seems prone to error.

In this instance I wish to include the HtmlAgilityPack from codeplex, so any example referencing this project would be good (https://htmlagilitypack.svn.codeplex.com/svn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [`svn:externals`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html) is for.  Since the source code is provided in the other repository, you will have to add a new project in your solution that builds that source, rather than including the DLLs.

Also, don’t forget the best practice of linking to a specific revision of the external repo (as opposed to HEAD) so that you have control over if and when to update your copy of their code.

#### EDIT

Given your target repository’s structure of

```
/Branches
    1.3.0
    1.4.0
/Release
    1_4_0_beta1
    1_4_0_beta2
/Trunk
```

I would link to something in the Release folder, e.g.

```
/Release/1_4_0_beta2/HtmlAgilityPack
```

You can also specify a revision number as a safeguard against something changing unexpectedly, but this is a tag and therefore they are unlikely to update it — they’ll just make a new tag.

Comment: I take it that I would ignore the /branches and /tags and just go for a -r on a /trunk revision?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like basically, `svn:external` is exactly what you need. Of course, the repository you are linking to must provide the files somehow. If it doesn't, I think you are not going to get around downloading and copying them on script level somehow.